# Java List list to String []

Tags: java, string, list, arraylist

How would I convert

```
List list= new ArrayList();
```

to

```
String [] profArr= {};
```

I have tried doing

```
profArr = list.toArrary() 

    and

profArr = (String [])list.toArrary()
```

I get the following error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.String;
```

I also have tried

```
String [] profArr= (String [])list.toArray(new String[0]);
```

and I get this error: The requested resource () is not available.

Here is how I create the list:

```
static List decode(int x)
    {
        List power2List = new ArrayList();
        if (x < 0) 
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Decode does not like negatives");
        while (x > 0)
        {
            int p2 = Integer.highestOneBit(x);
            x = x - p2;
            power2List.add(p2);
        }
        return power2List;   
    }

List list= new ArrayList();
list= decode(rset.getInt("favprofs")); //rset being a result set which pulls one int
```

Comment: What is your original list of? Does it have a `toString()` Method implemented?

Comment: The message about "The requested resource () is not available." has nothing to do with this code; something weird just happened that one time.

Comment: Also have you tried list.toArray(new String[0])

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to be using `list.toArray(new String[list.size()])`. An `Object[]` is not type compatible with `String[]`, despite every element in the `Object[]` being a `String`. Also, you should consider specifying the type parameter of your `List` to maintain type safety.

Comment: I get: The requested resource () is not available. mmm i wonder if something else is wrong then

Comment: @user975044 Without seeing more of your code or the full error message, I can only assume something else is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to use

> String profArr = list.toArray( < String array > (size))

Comment: This code won't even compile.  `list.toArray` returns an array, not a `String`.

Comment: I meant this one which seems to have already been provided as an answer list.toArray( new String[list.size]) where in my case <String array is basically any string object array and its size definition>

Answer (score 0):

you can use java collector

```
List<Tuple2<String, Boolean>> paras_check
String miss_params= paras_check.stream().map(e->e._1)
            .reduce(",",(x,y)->(x+y));
```